# Could someone explain me the basic tutorial of TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to get through the second section of the first tutorial of TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

"Basic Usage":

```
import tensorflow as tf
# NumPy is often used to load, manipulate and preprocess data.
import numpy as np

# Declare list of features. We only have one real-valued feature. There are many
# other types of columns that are more complicated and useful.
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]

# An estimator is the front end to invoke training (fitting) and evaluation
# (inference). There are many predefined types like linear regression,
# logistic regression, linear classification, logistic classification, and
# many neural network classifiers and regressors. The following code
# provides an estimator that does linear regression.
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

# TensorFlow provides many helper methods to read and set up data sets.
# Here we use two data sets: one for training and one for evaluation
# We have to tell the function how many batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_train}, y_train,
                                              batch_size=4,
                                              num_epochs=1000)
eval_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x":x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)

# We can invoke 1000 training steps by invoking the  method and passing the
# training data set.
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

# Here we evaluate how well our model did.
train_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
eval_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print("train loss: %r"% train_loss)
print("eval loss: %r"% eval_loss)
```

Could someone explain me, where is the computational graph hidden in this code?
I don't see any calls to `tf.Graph()` or `tf.Session()`.

What is the `features` variable used for? The data seem to never get in it, since the data provider is 'input_fn'.
How can I see the actual computational graph for the session and the graph?

Why are there two places where I set the number of epochs? (`estimator.fit` and `numpy_input_fn`)

What if I have two different estimators with `estimator1.fit(..., steps=20)` and `estimator2.fit(..., steps=50)`?
Do I need to set `num_epochs=70`? Or `num_epochs=max(20,50)`?
How can the `input_fn` control the number of threads, if it is called from `fit`, not vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Where is the tf.Graph() ot tf.Session()?

> Tensorflow creates a default computational graphs for you. So all the
>   variables and operations you have defined above will be on the default
>   graph. Sessions are defined inside the estimator functions. For
>   example estimator.fit() creates a Monitored training session.

2. What is features variable used for?

> It is used to init the LinearRegressor() model. The linear regression parameters are set based on the feature variables.

3. epochs set at input_fn and estimator?

> The input_fn is a queue, so the epoch in 'input_fn' tells how many times
>   each input data needs to be popped into the queue. The epoch in 'fit' measures
>   how many times each input  needs to be used in training. So if your fit epoch is greater than queue epoch, the training will stop when the queue
>   stops.

4. Queue size for two different estimator.

> The 'input_fn' epoch should be greater than or equal to sum of the
>   epochs in the estimators.